# Maintain Focus with two textbox and button using Brightscript

Tags: focus, roku, brightscript

I created a one Login Form in the bright script. It's following

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

**TextBox 1**  ' Here the focus is active I set by default in TextBox field active = true

**TextBox 2**  ' Here the press down key to active true

**Button 1** ' Here again press down key to focus true

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Here, I maintain the 3 Items using 3 different key. Now I want to maintain the single key for all 3 items using the down key. Anyone idea to How to maintain Focus using Brightscript.

I used the one function for key handling It's here

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean

.................

end function
```

Now, I maintained the key like
I set TextBox Focus active in ByDefault to XML File.Now I apply Logic to below.
First item focus set on XML file by default.

```
if key = "down" then 
       'Here Second item focus
       m.keypass.active = true ' Here work successfully First time
       if key = "down" and m.keypass.active = true and m.btnsub.active = false then
          'Here not maintain successfully its directly call here I press the down key.       
           m.keypass.active = false    
           m.btnsub.active = true 'Here third item focus is not maintained 

       end if
end if
```

I first-time press the down key It's working fine But its second time How handling the Focus. I used the same thing in Up key.

Here I am using "and" then the issue will happen is there any idea.

Pls, Check Here's an image really what I want to do.
[image]

**Edited Post:**

I handle with up and down key with below code. It's working But, Its only work in a single time.

```
 if key = "up" or key = "down"  
        if key = "down" 

          ?"here down key"

            if m.keypass.id = "instructpass" and m.keypass.active = true
                  ? "down key if part"
                  m.btngrp.setFocus(true)
                  m.keypass.active = false         
                  handled = true
            else if m.keyid.id = "instructid" and m.keyid.active = true 
                ?" down key else part"     
                m.keypass.active = true
                m.keyid.active = false
                handled = true
            else if m.btngrp.buttonSelected = 0
                m.keyid.active = true
                m.btngrp.setFocus(false)
                handled = true              
            end if 

            handled = true

       else if key = "up" 

         ? "here up key"

           if  m.keypass.active = true
                  ?"up key if part"
                  m.keyid.active = true
                  m.keypass.active = false
                  handled = true
           else if  m.keyid.active = true
                  ?"id key"
                  m.btngrp.setFocus(true)
                  m.btngrp.focusButton = 1
                  m.keyid.active = false        
                  handled = true

           else if m.btngrp.focusButton = 0 and m.btngrp.buttonSelected = 0
                ?"up key else part"
                m.keypass.active = true
                m.keypass.setFocus(true)     
                m.btngrp.setFocus(false)
                handled = true

            end if

                handled = true
        end if
        handled = true
end if
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you want to achieve? Description is not very clear as it is. What do you mean by "I want to maintain the single key for all 3 items using down key"?

Comment: @Thenaz here my question-related zip file. https://github.com/chaklasiyanikunj/KeyboardDialogExample

Comment: @Thenaz I Edit my Post pls check.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifsgnodefocus.md#isinfocuschain-as-boolean).

You should use .setFocus(true) and .hasFocus(), which are available to most renderable nodes such as TextEditBox and Button.

E.g.

```
if key = "down" then 
    if textBox1.hasFocus() then 
        textBox2.setFocus(true)
    elseif textBox2.hasFocus() then 
        button.setFocus(true)
    end if
end if

if key = "up" then 
    if button.hasFocus() then 
        textBox2.setFocus(true)
    elseif textBox2.hasFocus() then 
        textBox1.setFocus(true)
    end if
end if
```

Comment: I used the  `<TextEditBox 
      id = "instructid" 
      width = "780"
      hintText = "Email"
      cursorPosition = "0" 
      active = "true"
      clearOnDownKey = "true"
      translation = "[250,300]"
       />
      
      <TextEditBox 
      id = "instructpass" 
      width = "780"
      hintText = "Password"
      cursorPosition = "0"
      clearOnDownKey = "true"
      secureMode = "true"
      translation = "[250,400]"
       />  `  pls check my field attribute is thier any changes in here

Comment: I believe you are mixing two concepts, 'focus' and 'active'. To navigate between components you should set your focus to whichever component you are now on. Active, on the other hand, is an attribute on TextEditBox to display the cursor.
Ideally, you should navigate up/down while updating the styling of the component (eg. show a border or change background color to identify which one is focused), then press Ok to enter "edit" mode, which should display a keyboard and set active=true.

Comment: I think you have a problem with the logic here, when textbox1 has focus and the user presses 'down' you will assign focus to textbox2 then in the next `if`, textbox2 may have focus and immediately you will move focus to the next item.  For this reason I suggest you edit your answer to use `else if` in each of the two keypress handlers.

Comment: @RubenFreitas I Edit my post pls check

Comment: Here, First setFocus nothing and give "textBox1.setFocus(true)" and press down to all control set to textBox1 fine But I again press down then always press value print is false in the console log. I did not maintain cursor as smoothly. I required Focus because I apply another logic It is I'm on textbox1 and press ok to open a dialog box for input and down to jump another textbox.