# How to remove focus in ButtonGroup without any Method using Brightscript?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am using one button group and I set focus to Button Group using focusButton and buttonSelected. But focusButton set the first button Focus using 0 indexes and second button focus using 1 index successfully.

I tried to remove focus if I press up key then remove focus from button group.

I successfully with m.btngrp.setFocus(false) But, Issue is this method calling time my keyevent is not working.

Does anyone know that issue?

**Edited Post**

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean

? "press value : " press
? "key value : " key
handled = false   
if press = true then    
   if m.keyid.active = true and key = "OK" then
   ?"Email Ok Press"            
        showdialogid()   
        return handled 

   else if m.keypass.active = true and key = "OK" then
        ?"Password Ok Press"

                showdialogpass()
                return handled 
   end if
   return handled 
end if

if press = false then     

      if key = "OK" and m.btnLogout.focusBitmapUri <> ""

         ?"Click the Logout button"

         m.btnLogout.visible = false
         m.btnLogout.focusBitmapUri = ""
         m.loginscreengrp.visible = true
         m.keyid.active = true
         return true

      else if key = "OK" and m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri <> "" 

        ?"Click the sign-in button"

         m.loginscreengrp.visible = false
         m.btnLogout.visible = true
         m.btnLogout.setFocus(true)
         m.btnLogout.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/Logout.png"
         m.btnLogout.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
         return true

      end if 

      if key = "up" or key = "down"

            if key = "down"
                    ?"here down key"

                    if m.keypass.active = true 

                        m.keypass.setFocus(false)
                        m.keypass.active = false
                        m.btnsubmit.setFocus(true)
                        m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/newsignin.png"
                        m.btnsubmit.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
                        handled = true

                    else if m.keyid.active = true

                        m.keyid.setFocus(false)
                        m.keyid.active = false
                        m.keypass.setFocus(true)
                        m.keypass.active = true
                        handled = true

                    else if m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri <> "" 
                        ? "setting active and key down press " 
                        m.btnsubmit.setFocus(false)
                        m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri = "" 
                        m.btnsetting.setFocus(true)
                        m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/newsetting.png"
                        m.btnsetting.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
                        handled = true

                    else if m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri <> "" 
                       ? "id active and key down press"
                       m.btnsetting.setFocus(false)
                       m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri = ""
                       m.keyid.setFocus(true)
                       m.keyid.active = true
                       handled  = true

                    end if
                    handled = true

            else if key = "up"

                    ? "here up key"
                    if m.keypass.active = true 

                        ?"id active and press up"
                        m.keypass.active = false
                        m.keyid.active = true
                        handled = true

                    else if m.keyid.active = true 

                        ?"setting active and press up"

                        m.keyid.active = false
                        m.btnsetting.setFocus(true)
                        m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/newsetting.png"
                        m.btnsetting.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
                        handled = true

                    else if m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri <> "" 
                         ?"submit active and press up"

                         m.btnsetting.focusBitmapUri = ""
                         m.btnsetting.setFocus(false)
                         m.btnsubmit.setFocus(true)
                         m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/newsignin.png"
                         m.btnsubmit.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
                         handled = true

                    else if m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri <> "" 

                        ? "pass active and press up"                         
                        'press = false
                        ? "press value active : " press 
                        m.btnsubmit.focusBitmapUri = ""
                        m.btnsubmit.setFocus(false)
                        m.keypass.setFocus(true)
                        m.keypass.active = true
                        handled = true
                    end if
                    handled = true
                end if
                handled = true
            end if
        return handled
   end if
   return true
end function
```

Comment: "Setting the remote control focus to false is rarely necessary, and can lead to unexpected behavior."
Instead of setting focus false, you should set the focus onto something else: `otherNode.setFocus(true)`

Comment: Thank you for an answer I satisfied with you But In my code, I used `if press then` First time found the press value true then I Set the setFocus(true) then by Default its change the press value to false. any other way to Manage the press value

Comment: the press value is false when the user releases the key.  press=false means the button moved back to unpressed.  both press and unpress are received by your keyhandler, normally you should ignore unpress (take no action if press=false).

Comment: Thank you. It's very very helpful to me.

Comment: u know about that is no concept of Redirect screen in Roku. So, I tried all widget put on single Group and use Hide/show concept. Is there any way to use Redirect or navigate Screen?.

Comment: sry, but In a textbox, I store a value from a keyboard but the first time is successfully stored the second time its generate issue. I think its refresh the screen. I edit my post and out my code pls check these code. It functions for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967997/maintain-focus-with-two-textbox-and-button-using-brightscript to maintain focus but It's not working properly at Textbox active true and I press an ok button its key call every time in the keyboard so I don't write to any email or password.